# webpack SyntaxError: Block-scoped declarations (let, const, function, class) not yet supported outside strict mode

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

I've tried adding the npm package [hard-source-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/mzgoddard/hard-source-webpack-plugin) to my project. As written in the docs, I only should add

```
var HardSourceWebpackPlugin = require('hard-source-webpack-plugin');
```

When running webpack I got the following error:

```
D:\Projects\MyProject\node_modules\hard-source-webpack-plugin\index.js:49
let ops = 0;
^^^
SyntaxError: Block-scoped declarations (let, const, function, class) not yet supported outside strict mode
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:373:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:404:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Projects\MyProject\webpack.config.js:6:31)
    at Module._compile (module.js:397:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:404:10)
Process terminated with code 1.
```

I've installed the latest `Node.js` which is currently version 10.5.0.

Comment: *"I've installed the latest Node.jsm wich is currently version 10.5.0."* If you're getting that error, that's not the version of Node you're running when you get that error. You appear to have an old version of Node installed which is getting used instead.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I've uninstalled the previous version, which was `8.9.0` prior the update to new version. Any chance I can check which other versions may be around there?

Comment: Of course you can. *How* you do so will depend on your OS and how you installed the earlier versions. It's something you're going to have to work through at your end, we can't really do much for you here. But for instance, on \*nix systems, you can use `which node` to see which one is run from a given terminal, you can use `find` to find other copies, and you can look in the Webpack script to see how it determines which one to call (if it doesn't just rely on the one in the path).

Comment: It should not matter what versions of node you have installed.  If doing `node -v` gives you the version you need your good to go.

Comment: A quick fix would be to simple run your code in strict mode… Maybe also report a bug that they should add `"use strict";` to the top of their module.